# transition screen of tabnavigator from stacknavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used TabNavigator in the main.js file

```
const TabsNav =  TabNavigator({
      sccreen1: {
        screen: screen1
      },
      screen2: {
        screen: screen2
      },

    },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
         tabBarVisible: false,
     }),

  });
```

I used the following code in the today.js file

```
class TodayMenu extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'today',
    headerBackTitle: null,
  }
}

export default TodayMenu = StackNavigator(
  {
    First: {screen: TodayMenu},
    Second: {screen: DetailsProduct}
  }
)
```

I'm going to transition the screen today to screen1 or screen2, which code should i use?

Comment: You need to have only one navigator and others should be nested in it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have stackNavigator you should define a button or somthing like that and use

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('destination screen')
```

you can find more about it [hear](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html)